# Sort appearence order in the_content()

Tags: html, sort, order, the-content

I have an About the Author plugin, echoing inside the_content(), and a Facebook Like Button, that I hardcoded in the HTML, after the_content(), here's how it is outputting:

[image]

The Facebook Like button should appear prior than the Author Box

Single.php (handcoded by me, probably with some bad practices as I'm noob at PHP):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="fb-recommendations-bar" data-site="criatweb.com" data-trigger="50%" data-read-time="10" data-side="right" data-action="like"></div>
    <div class="blog roundedall" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div class="bcontainer contentpadded">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <h1 class="blog-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <h4 class="blog-author">por <?php the_author_link(); ?> </h4>
            <h3 class="blog-categories">Em <?php the_category(' , ') ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            <div class="blog-subfooter">
                <div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments width="450" count="on" num="10" title="Faça o social :)" countmsg="comments"]'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I know **why** it is outputting bellow the author box, but I don't know how to **FIX** it.

I've tried do_shortcode the [Biographia plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-biographia/), but then it enters a infinite loop, echoing the post over and over again

Comment: Can you provide a link to the *About the Author* plugin? ... or is it the *Biographia* plugin?

Comment: It is the Biographia plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add the *Facebook-Like* html code via this filter:

```
/**
 * Append Facebook Like to the content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return string $content
 */
function custom_the_content( $content )
{
    $fblike = '<div class="fb-like" 
                    data-layout="button_count" 
                    data-action="like" 
                    data-show-faces="false" 
                    data-share="false">
              </div>';

    return $content . $fblike;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_the_content', 9, 1 );
```

if the priority of the *author box* is `10`.

Otherwise you could adjust the priority via the *Biographia* settings page:

[image: Biographia settings page]

so you would have:

```
priority("facebook like") < priority("author box")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! It's great to learn about adding custom code to the_content, real useful